# Docker and Laravel 8 migrate issue

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I've followed this tutorial [docker tutorial](https://youtu.be/5N6gTVCG_rw) and it is an awesome tutorial by the way.
Installed an 8 Laravel version and when I tried to run PHP artisan migrate, this problem came out:

```
 ParseError 

  syntax error, unexpected ')'

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/BusServiceProvider.php:51
     47▕             return new DatabaseBatchRepository(
     48▕                 $app->make(BatchFactory::class),
     49▕                 $app->make('db')->connection(config('queue.batching.database')),
     50▕                 config('queue.batching.table', 'job_batches'),
  ➜  51▕             );
     52▕         });
     53▕     }
     54▕ 
     55▕     /**

      +1 vendor frames 
  2   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass("Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider")

      +5 vendor frames 
  8   artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

And I guess this is linked to Laravel 8 when running into a Docker environment.

Let's see the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

The docker containers are up and running perfectly so what could be?

Comment: Read the docs, you need PHP 7.3+

Comment: Oh, ok! Cool! I'll upgrade to 7.3!

Comment: Thanks @FelippeDuarte! It works like a breeze!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change php version in the Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```